# Find all links of a website using JavaScript or PHP/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, regex

What is the best practice to find all links of an external website? I had a look around and it seems JavaScript along cannot scrape external sites because of the same origin policy. With PHP I can easily get a website's content with the `file_get_contents()` function but how do I extract links only? Do I need to write a regex or is there any other, better way of doing this?

Comment: Your question is not duplicated.. anyway this may help you work: http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/extract-links-html-file-php

Comment: Cheers, [Simple HTML Dom Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) seems like what I was looking for!